# Unable to log into AskUbuntu or other Stack Exchange sites

Tags: discussion, login, askubuntu

I was unable to log in to AskUbuntu, I was basically stuck on the sign in process. Every time I wanted to log in, after seeing the login page, I used to get signed in automatically (because I have the LastPass Firefox plugin) and I used to see AskUbuntu's welcome banner at the top of the page, but then after the banner disappeared, I wasn't signed in.

Comment: This is a self-answered question. I encountered this problem and there wasn't any answer on the web, so I thought it might be helpful to let the others know about it, just in case they face the same problem.

Comment: I have a devil of a time logging in using Firefox.  The login pages take login and password, but then just refuse to do anything more.  I just succeeded after over 10 tries, reboots, etc.  FF 44.0.2, OSX El Capitan.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I thought the problem is either with the LastPass plugin, or either Firefox's cache or the local storage object (HTML5 feature) is corrupted. I cleared Firefox's cache, local storage, and offline data. I also deleted Stack Exchange and AskUbuntu's entries in my LastPass Vault. Restarted Firefox, tried to log in, and yeah, it worked! Then I added back the entries for AskUbuntu and Stack Exchange in my LastPass Vault. It works fine! I think the problem must have been with Firefox's offline data, local storage object, or probably the cache.

Hope this helps others.